# ggplot2 and grid.arrange, place legend below arranged plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am facing a problem when I arrange 2 ggplots next to each other using `grid.arrange()`.
I want to place a legend evenly below both plots.

So I have (pseudocode):

```
 p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(group = name, color=as.factor(fac), y = ys, x= (xs))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")

 p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(group = name, color=as.factor(fac), y = ys, x= (xs))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +

  grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=2, widths=c(0.9,1))
```

Is there any possibility to arrange the legend so that it is positioned evenly below both plots? If I do it as above, the legend is (logically) placed below the first plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With package `patchwork` you could try this...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(group = gear, color=as.factor(am), y = mpg, x = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()

p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(group = gear, color=as.factor(am), y = mpg, x = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()

p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
  theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>